# Улучшение характеристик юнитов

Tags: c#

```
class Unit
    {
        public string name;
        public int health;
        public int MaxHealth;
        public int armor;
        public int damage;
        public bool IsAlive;
            
        public Unit(string name, int health, int armor, int damage)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.health = health;
            this.MaxHealth = this.health;
            this.damage = damage;
            this.armor = armor;
            this.IsAlive = true;
        }
    }
```

Требуется реализация еще одного метода на подобии под этим заголовком, но он должен выполнять улучшения все существующих юнитов

```
class Smithy : Unit
    {
        int lvl;
        public Smithy() : base("Smithy", 40, 0, 0)
        {
            this.lvl = 0;
        }

        public void UpgradeUnit(Unit unit)
        {
            if (this.lvl <= 2)
            {
                this.lvl++;
                unit.damage += 20;
                unit.health += 20;
                
                Console.WriteLine($"the {unit.name} lvl up");
                Console.WriteLine($"{unit.damage} {unit.health} {lvl}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"the {unit.name} max lvl");
            }
        }

        public void UpgradeAllUnit()
        {
        }
    }
```

## Юниты: маг, воин, лучник

```
public Mage() : base("Wizard", 60, 4, 40)
{
    this.Mana = 1000;
    this.MaxMana = this.Mana;
}

public FootMan() : base("footman", 80, 7, 20)
{

}

public Archer() : base("Archer", 70, 5, 20)
{
    this.Arrows = 20;
}
```

Comment: что такое `Smithy`? Кузница? зачем кузнице хп? почему кузница наследуется от юнита, если по факту это не персонаж; не совсем это понятно...

Comment: почему в примере классов-наследников не сами классы, а только их конструкторы?

Comment: `улучшения все существующих юнитов` - существующих где? имеется в виду что есть объекты классов `Mage`, `FootMan`, `Archer` и у этих объектов надо повысить характеристики? ну тогда создай массив юнитов и передавай его в `UpgradeAllUnit` -  `public void UpgradeAllUnit(List<Unit> units)`